# Bulk update for customer databases

Tags: sql-server, deployment, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have 10 customer databases (SQL Server) with the same schema design, stored procedures, functions, etc. I need to change schema design and some functions but I don't want to do one by one. I want to design a system to modify things once and push changes to all databases automatically. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you have 10 separate, but identical, databases then?

Comment: @Larnu I would argue that's outside the scope of this question. This is a very common design in businesses that have a DB per client (single tenant).

Comment: I would argue it is, @ChadBaldwin, 1 database, 1 deployment. We don't know why the OP has chosen to have 10 identical databases.

Comment: Look at tools like [DbUp](https://dbup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which allow you to create your SQL change scripts, and compile those into an executable, which you can then run 10 or 100 times, against each of your database

Answer (score 0):

I would look into one of two products, these are the ones I have some experience or knowledge of, but there are absolutely more tools out there that will solve your question:

1. [dbatools.io](https://dbatools.io) - this is a powershell suite that allows you to interact with SQL Server using PowerShell. You can write scripts that run your schema changes on multiple databases and even multiple servers. However, it's up to you to handle rollbacks, error handling, validation, etc. But it does make the job much easier.
2. [RedGate Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) - I don't personally have much experience with this tool. But from what I have found in searching for this answer, that it may be a solution for you. See this blog post from RedGate for deploying to multiple databases:
   https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/flyway/automating-migrations-for-multiple-databases-using-flyway

Comment: This site is specifically not for recommending products or tools.

Comment: @DaleK All answers of the form "using library X will solve your problem" are recommendations of products and tools. OP asked how to design something, and the answer happens to be "use one of these existing tools". There is no need to scold people who answer, just vote to close the question if you think it's a poor fit and move on.

Comment: @StephenJennings no scolding happening here. Many people aren't aware of that until someone tells them.